# Creating video skim of YUV video in matab

Tags: matlab, video, dataframe, video-processing, yuv

I am having Y,U,V components of some frames and now I want to create a video from these components. To be more specific I want to create video summary of a video. Till now I have obtained which frames needs to be there (after some processing) in final video skim and I want to generate a video skim from these frames.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
I have created video skim but I doubt that might not be the most efficient method. What I am doing is first I am storing the required frame's Y,U,V component in a cell then I am using frwrite function of matlab.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried already so far. This will increase the chance of good answers.

Comment: I have create video skim but I doubt that might not be the most efficient method. What I am doing is first I am storing the requited frame's Y,U,V component in a cell then I am using frwrite function of matlab.

Comment: Comments are temporary. Add clarification by editing your question. Please include your code.